# How to make a timer in Android Studio 1.0.2?

Tags: java, android, optimization, time, android-studio

I have this code and my app is crashing at startup. This code is from onCreate method.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView txtClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClicks);
            // task to be done every 1000 milliseconds
            iClicks = iClicks + 1;
            txtClicks.setText(String.valueOf(iClicks));
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: What is the crash and where? I am gonna bet it is either because your value iClicks isn't set prior to `iClicks = iClicks + 1;` or you are getting a NPE from `txtClicks.setText(String.valueOf(iClicks));`

Comment: @zgc7009 I don't know. I have declared int iClicks = 0 in class but when i added int iClicks = 0 to TimerTask class -> app is crashing too but with changed Text from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're inside a different `thread`. You can only modify your UI from the `UIThread`. You should use:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {      
    @Override
    public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
        TextView txtClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClicks);
        // task to be done every 1000 milliseconds
        iClicks = iClicks + 1;
        txtClicks.setText(String.valueOf(iClicks));
        }
  });

    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code, with timerLoopScan and scanPeriod being global variables :

```
    timerLoopScan = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                    loopScan(); // your processings here
            });
        }
    };
    timerLoopScan.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, scanPeriod);
```